# non-deterministic polynomial solutions over deterministic polynomial solution

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np

Non-Deterministic Polynomial  solutions are always not desirable over Deterministic Polynomial solutions is it true? Please give an appropriate reasoning.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please provide more details.

Comment: I realise this has been closed, I don't think any of the answers get at what he is asking. The question is better stated "Is a P algorithm always more preferable than an algorithm which is in NP but not in P (a.k.a. NP-P)?" As an answer I would say it depends on the situation. Case and point, in cryptography, you will almost always prefer a NP algorithm to solve your code than a P one. In general, when the goal is actually solving the problem, and not to prevent it from being solved, a P solution is better than an NP solution that is not in P. this is assuming that we dont know if P=NP

Answer (score 2):

Every deterministic polynomial solution can be translated to a non-deterministic polynomial one [since [P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29) is a subset of [NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29)]

We do not know if the oposite is true or not [we do not know if P=NP or P!=NP], so if P!=NP, there are problems [all [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problems] , which we have non deterministic polynomial solutions, but not polynomial solutions.

Thus, since we can convert deterministic polynomial solution to a non-deterministic polynomial solution, but we do not know if we can do the oposite - **if we have a deterministic polynomial solution - we actuall have also the nondeterministic one.**

Comment: Non deterministic and NP (non polynomial) are very different things.

Comment: @ElKamina: NP stands for Non-deterministic Polynomial, and not non polynomial. Shortest path for instacne, is both P and NP problem. [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) however, is in NP, but only in P if P=NP. I recommend you read the [wikipedia page for NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) which starts at: "he abbreviation NP refers to "nondeterministic polynomial time."

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to amit's informative answer, sometimes - for practical inputs - NP solutions can be better. For instance, consider an exponential algorithm for an NP problem which has T(n) = 2^n. Consider a problem whose best-case time complexity is provably T(n) = (1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,009)n^2. That's polynomial, but I'd probably rather solve the exponential problem.

If the question is whether, for the same problem, you'd rather use a an exponential-or-worse solution or a polynomial solution, generally the answer is this: it depends on your input size. Algorithms with higher asymptotic complexities can be faster for most inputs of reasonable size; although there will be a point where it makes sense to use the lower-complexity algorithm, that point may never be reached in practice (or in the lifetime of the universe).

EDIT: It can also depend upon other characteristics of the input. For instance, quicksort can outperform mergesort, although mergesort is provably better than quicksort in the worst case. If you know it's very unlikely for your data to be in a form such that it's the worst-case for quicksort, quicksort might be worth trying.